# Iterator vs List

Tags: java, collections

What is the difference between list and iterator and enumeration in java?
Apart from below,

1. List is a an array with some added advantage.
2. Iterator is used to traverse through collection object.
3. Enumeration is the old version of iterator with less methods(functions).

Comment: While conceptually your `#1` point is correct, lists and arrays in Java are very different things.  You might want to brush up with a good tutorial at this point.

Comment: I know about them.

Comment: This question is too general and I think a lot of answers are available.

Comment: Your point #1 is only correct if we talk about `ArrayList`; it is incorrect if we talk about `LinkedList`. `List` is a type of `Collection`; `Collection`(s) are `Iterable`. Basically, it's a way to abstract the concept of a container (a thing containing other things) and a consistent way to traverse *any* type of container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enumerator cannot modify the collection it is working on. Whereas an Iterator can. Also iterator is fail fast and enumerator is fail safe meaning if another thread modifies the collection the iterator is working on it will throw exception whereas an enumerator will not. These are the kind of fundamental differences between the two. Both have a similiar purpose but have different features and properties build on. Both of these are different from List where List is the actual data structure which holds the data vs Iterator and Enumerator which are interfaces that allow access to work on the underlying collection.